# Trigger for checking duplicate email address

Tags: mysql, triggers

Is it a good option to write mysql trigger to check duplicate email address.So, that Mysql reject the insertion of duplicate email address.

Or,

It is good to do in application ? i.e  read all email address from user table and then in PHP do the comparison.

I am reading about mysql trigger and I though it would be good option instead of doing in php ..Kindly advice.

Regards,

Comment: You don't need a trigger. Just add a `UNIQUE` constraint on the column.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, database triggers are more efficient and better, because you can't forget to implement them in your application.

And the second thing is, why don't you set the email-address column as unique?